# Getting folders in dir then their sub-folders

Tags: php

### PHP Code:

```
<?php
    echo '<ul class="DirView"><li><a href="#">Recently Used<span>28</span></a></li>';
    $path = "../Desktop/";
    $dir = new DirectoryIterator($path);
    foreach ($dir as $fileinfo) {
        if ($fileinfo->isDir() && !$fileinfo->isDot()) {
            $subPath = $path.$fileinfo->getFilename();
            $subDir = new DirectoryIterator($subPath);
            echo '<li><a href="#">'.$fileinfo->getFilename().'<span>28</span></a><ul>';
            foreach ($subDir as $subPath) {
                if ($fileinfo->isDir() && !$fileinfo->isDot()) {
                    echo '<li><a href="#">'.$fileinfo->getFilename().'<span>18</span></a><li>';
                }
            }
            echo '</ul></li>';
        }
    }
    echo '</ul>';
?>
```

### Problem:

My while loop inside my while loop is not displaying the sub-folders.

### What the outcome looks like:

```
<ul class="DirView">
    <li><a href="#" class="">Recently Used<span>28</span></a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#" class="active">CSS<span>28</span></a>
        <ul style="display: block;">
            <li><a href="#">CSS<span>18</span></a>
            </li>
            <li></li>
            <li><a href="#">CSS<span>18</span></a>
            </li>
            <li></li>
            <li><a href="#">CSS<span>18</span></a>
            </li>
            <li></li>
            <li><a href="#">CSS<span>18</span></a>
            </li>
            <li></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#" class="">JS<span>28</span></a>
        <ul style="display: none;">
            <li><a href="#">JS<span>18</span></a>
            </li>
            <li></li>
            <li><a href="#">JS<span>18</span></a>
            </li>
            <li></li>
            <li><a href="#">JS<span>18</span></a>
            </li>
            <li></li>
            <li><a href="#">JS<span>18</span></a>
            </li>
            <li></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#" class="">IMG<span>28</span></a>
        <ul style="display: none;">
            <li><a href="#">IMG<span>18</span></a>
            </li>
            <li></li>
            <li><a href="#">IMG<span>18</span></a>
            </li>
            <li></li>
            <li><a href="#">IMG<span>18</span></a>
            </li>
            <li></li>
            <li><a href="#">IMG<span>18</span></a>
            </li>
            <li></li>
            <li><a href="#">IMG<span>18</span></a>
            </li>
            <li></li>
            <li><a href="#">IMG<span>18</span></a>
            </li>
            <li></li>
            <li><a href="#">IMG<span>18</span></a>
            </li>
            <li></li>
            <li><a href="#">IMG<span>18</span></a>
            </li>
            <li></li>
            <li><a href="#">IMG<span>18</span></a>
            </li>
            <li></li>
            <li><a href="#">IMG<span>18</span></a>
            </li>
            <li></li>
            <li><a href="#">IMG<span>18</span></a>
            </li>
            <li></li>
            <li><a href="#">IMG<span>18</span></a>
            </li>
            <li></li>
            <li><a href="#">IMG<span>18</span></a>
            </li>
            <li></li>
            <li><a href="#">IMG<span>18</span></a>
            </li>
            <li></li>
            <li><a href="#">IMG<span>18</span></a>
            </li>
            <li></li>
            <li><a href="#">IMG<span>18</span></a>
            </li>
            <li></li>
            <li><a href="#">IMG<span>18</span></a>
            </li>
            <li></li>
            <li><a href="#">IMG<span>18</span></a>
            </li>
            <li></li>
            <li><a href="#">IMG<span>18</span></a>
            </li>
            <li></li>
            <li><a href="#">IMG<span>18</span></a>
            </li>
            <li></li>
            <li><a href="#">IMG<span>18</span></a>
            </li>
            <li></li>
            <li><a href="#">IMG<span>18</span></a>
            </li>
            <li></li>
            <li><a href="#">IMG<span>18</span></a>
            </li>
            <li></li>
            <li><a href="#">IMG<span>18</span></a>
            </li>
            <li></li>
            <li><a href="#">IMG<span>18</span></a>
            </li>
            <li></li>
            <li><a href="#">IMG<span>18</span></a>
            </li>
            <li></li>
            <li><a href="#">IMG<span>18</span></a>
            </li>
            <li></li>
            <li><a href="#">IMG<span>18</span></a>
            </li>
            <li></li>
            <li><a href="#">IMG<span>18</span></a>
            </li>
            <li></li>
            <li><a href="#">IMG<span>18</span></a>
            </li>
            <li></li>
            <li><a href="#">IMG<span>18</span></a>
            </li>
            <li></li>
            <li><a href="#">IMG<span>18</span></a>
            </li>
            <li></li>
            <li><a href="#">IMG<span>18</span></a>
            </li>
            <li></li>
            <li><a href="#">IMG<span>18</span></a>
            </li>
            <li></li>
            <li><a href="#">IMG<span>18</span></a>
            </li>
            <li></li>
            <li><a href="#">IMG<span>18</span></a>
            </li>
            <li></li>
            <li><a href="#">IMG<span>18</span></a>
            </li>
            <li></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

This looks completely messed up I know but you don't get anywhere if you simply do not try! My previous working version just got the first level folders;

```
<?php
    echo '<ul class="DirView">';
    $path = "../Desktop/";
    $dir = new DirectoryIterator($path);
    foreach ($dir as $fileinfo) {
        if ($fileinfo->isDir() && !$fileinfo->isDot()) {
            echo '<li>'.$fileinfo->getFilename().'</li>';
        }
    }
    echo '</ul>';
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if I am completely 100% with this answer but you may have misused your variables in the inner foreach loop:

You are currently using `$fileinfo` instead of `$subPath`, try:

```
foreach ($subDir as $subPath) {
    if ($subPath->isDir() && !$subPath->isDot()) {
        echo '<li><a href="#">'.$subPath->getFilename().'<span>18</span></a><li>';
    }
}
```

Full Code

```
<?php
    echo '<ul class="DirView"><li><a href="#">Recently Used<span>28</span></a></li>';
    $path = "../Desktop/";
    $dir = new DirectoryIterator($path);
    foreach ($dir as $fileinfo) {
        if ($fileinfo->isDir() && !$fileinfo->isDot()) {
            $subPath = $path.$fileinfo->getFilename();
            $subDir = new DirectoryIterator($subPath);
            echo '<li><a href="#">'.$fileinfo->getFilename().'<span>28</span></a><ul>';
            foreach ($subDir as $subPath) {
                if ($subPath->isDir() && !$subPath->isDot()) {
                    echo '<li><a href="#">'.$subPath->getFilename().'<span>18</span></a><li>';
                }
            }
            echo '</ul></li>';
        }
    }
    echo '</ul>';
?>
```